# It is ok to use useRef(), localStorage and useState() in order to keep state data after refreshing the page?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**What I want to achieve, is to keep changes in the state between refresh.**
**Now I think about this solution below,** *(using localStorage with useRef())* but I'm suspicious about it, it seems like it isn't technically correct, what do you think about that? It is useRef() supposed to be used for cases like this one, or maybe there are other more convenient solutions? It is supposed to not use any database.
**Is a little project, a movie app, not a prod** or stuff like that, the 5mb from localStorage are pretty much enough.

**State (fetched from the API)**

```
 const [popularMovies, setPopularMovies] = useState(false);
```

**Fetch Data for state**

```
  function getPopularMoviesData() {
    const url =
      "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=60186105dc57d2473a4b079bdee2fa31&language=en-US&page=1";

    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setPopularMovies(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getPopularMoviesData();
  }, []);
```

**useRef()**

```
  const prevPopularMovies = useRef();
```

**keep our previous data after each re-render**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    prevPopularMovies.current = popularMovies;
    setPopularMovies(prevPopularMovies.current);
  });
```

**localStorage for keeping data on refresh**

```
useEffect(() => {
    const popularMoviesData = localStorage.getItem("popularMovies");

    if (popularMoviesData !== null) {
      setPopularMovies(JSON.parse(popularMoviesData));
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("popularMovies", JSON.stringify(popularMovies));
  }, [popularMovies]);
```

Comment: What is the bedrock of your question really? Using a React ref to cache a state value, or persisting local state to localStorage? You don't need to worry about persisting state from render to render since that is the default state behavior. I don't think a React ref is necessary for anything you are saying you are doing. `prevPopularMovies` doesn't appear to really be used.

Comment: I need to correct my answers title, I need to keep data between refresh page, not just between re-render...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is really just about persisting state through page reloads then all you really need is a state initializer function to initialize the state *from* localStorage, and the `useEffect` hook to save state updates *to* localStorage.

The `useState` hook will keep the `popularMovies` state value from render cycle to render cycle. There's nothing to worry about here as this is the default React state behavior, the state lives as long as the component is mounted.

Example:

```
const initializeState = () => {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("popularMovies")) || {};
};
```

...

```
const [popularMovies, setPopularMovies] = useState(initializeState);

useEffect(() => {
  if (!popularMovies?.results?.length) {
    getPopularMoviesData();
  }
  localStorage.setItem("popularMovies", JSON.stringify(popularMovies));
}, [popularMovies]);

function getPopularMoviesData() {
  const url =
    "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=60186105dc57d2473a4b079bdee2fa31&language=en-US&page=1";

  fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      setPopularMovies(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
}
```

[image: Edit it-is-ok-to-use-useref-localstorage-and-usestate-in-order-to-keep-state-dat]

Comment: I tried to do so with localStorage, without using useRef(), but, useEffect which fetches data, on refresh just reset my state to default and the localStorage.getItem logs the error json is undefined..

Comment: @rigan My answer is how you'd initialize and persist local state through page reloads. It seems that this data fetching is relevant, I don't see why the other `useEffect` hook calling `getPopularMoviesData` to fetch data would be an issue here. Can you clarify what exactly the issue is then that you are trying to resolve?

Comment: Here's the way I tried without using useRef():

Comment: `const [popularMovies, setPopularMovies] = useState();`

Comment: `function getPopularMoviesData() {
    const url =
      "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=60186105dc57d2473a4b079bdee2fa31&language=en-US&page=1";

    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setPopularMovies(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getPopularMoviesData();
  }, []);`

Comment: `useEffect(() => {
    const popularMoviesData = localStorage.getItem("popularMovies");

    if (popularMoviesData !== null) {
      setPopularMovies(JSON.parse(popularMoviesData));
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("popularMovies", JSON.stringify(popularMovies));
  }, [popularMovies]);`

Comment: So when I bookmark I movie, I changed the state, and I need to keep this changes after refresh, but the changes gets lost, without useRef() it doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: @rigan Here's a small demo [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/it-is-ok-to-use-useref-localstorage-and-usestate-in-order-to-keep-state-dat-4mdgh0?file=/src/App.js:589-835) of your code with the above changes applied to persist state. I've added additional console logs to explicitly show where the state is initialized/persisted from/to. I also added a link to the sandbox demo in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly do this as a way to cache state between reloads but ultimately this data can get lost if local storage is cleared on exit or for other reasons and so it is never a guarantee. One robust solution that attempts to solve this is [immortal db](https://github.com/gruns/ImmortalDB). This package will sync state between localstorage, cookies and indexdb in attempt to have the data persist.

Comment: It seems to be a good solution, but honestly I don't really want to implement something from outside if there is a way to solve that with localStorage. I just don't understand why I can't keep data changes between refreshes...